# php xml pagination issues missing one result

Tags: php, xml, pagination

the following code i set to have results from xml put into pagination, it is working for the most part, but it is missing a line each time.

so i have it set at 7 it only shows 6 results per page
here is my Code:

```
$thispage= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$startPage = $_GET['page'];
$perPage =7;
$currentRecord = 0;

/  Start XML Parsing
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->load('Playlist.xml');

    $xmlPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $arrNodes = $xmlPath->query('//channels/channel');

         foreach($arrNodes as $item){

         $currentRecord += 1;
         if($currentRecord > ($startPage * $perPage) && $currentRecord < ($startPage * $perPage + $perPage)){

       // Get Name
        $id=$item->getAttribute('id');

        // lets limit title
        $string=$item->getAttribute('name');
        $finTitle = (strlen($string) > 55) ? substr($string,0,52).'...' : $string;

        // lets limit  category
        $cat=$item->getAttribute('category'); 
        $category= (strlen($cat) > 20) ? substr($cat,0,17).'...' : $cat;
        // now we have the URL to pass on
        $vidUrl=$item->getAttribute('url'); 

    if($bgcolor=='#f1f1f1'){$bgcolor='#ffffff';}
    else{$bgcolor='#f1f1f1';}

    echo "<tr >";
    echo "<td bgcolor=$bgcolor id='title ' align=center>&nbsp;<font face='Verdana' size='2'>$id</font></td>"; 
    echo "<td bgcolor=$bgcolor id='title' align=center>&nbsp;<font face='Verdana' size='2'>$finTitle</font></td>";
    echo "<td bgcolor=$bgcolor id='title' align=center>&nbsp;<font face='Verdana' size='2'>$category</a></font></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Thanks i am sure i am just missing something somewhere  at first i thought it was here :
**$currentRecord += 1;**  but if i change that to just 1 or 0 it will not show any results

also next page will start at 8  totally missing the 7th result  next page after that will start at 15

Comment: The page variable, does it start at 0 or 1?

Comment: what page variable?  that is pretty much all the code

Comment: When you click on page 1 in the pagination, what does the link look like?

Comment: I would say it starts from zero.  But the indexes start from one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be easier to follow the code if $currentRecord started from zero.  $currentRecord gets incremented by one right away, so the first *used* value is one.

In the following code, it starts from zero:

```
<?php
$thispage= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$startPage = $_GET['page'];
$perPage =7;
$currentRecord = 0;

//  Start XML Parsing
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('Playlist.xml');

$xmlPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$arrNodes = $xmlPath->query('//channels/channel');

$startIdx = $startPage * $perPage;
$endIdx = ($startPage + 1) * $perPage;

foreach($arrNodes as $currentRecord => $item){

  if(($currentRecord >= $startIdx) && ($currentRecord < $endIdx)) {

    // Get Name
    $id=$item->getAttribute('id');

    // lets limit title
    $string=$item->getAttribute('name');
    $finTitle = (strlen($string) > 55) ? substr($string,0,52).'...' : $string;

    // lets limit  category
    $cat=$item->getAttribute('category'); 
    $category= (strlen($cat) > 20) ? substr($cat,0,17).'...' : $cat;
    // now we have the URL to pass on
    $vidUrl=$item->getAttribute('url'); 

    if($bgcolor=='#f1f1f1'){$bgcolor='#ffffff';}
    else{$bgcolor='#f1f1f1';}

    echo "<tr >";
    echo "<td bgcolor=$bgcolor id='title ' align=center>&nbsp;<font face='Verdana' size='2'>$id</font></td>"; 
    echo "<td bgcolor=$bgcolor id='title' align=center>&nbsp;<font face='Verdana' size='2'>$finTitle</font></td>";
    echo "<td bgcolor=$bgcolor id='title' align=center>&nbsp;<font face='Verdana' size='2'>$category</a></font></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
}
?>
```

Is that any better?  Sorry -- I didn't actually try it myself.  I also didn't fix the multiple occurrences of "id='title'" nor put in a default for $startPage.  There's probably more.

Comment: Yes that did it... and yes i am sure there is plenty to clean up!  im learning @harry